# {Ionic /Angular 4} ERR! code PeerInvalid when i try to run myapp on an android device

Tags: node.js, angular, cordova, ionic-framework

I use Ionic since 3 days, and today i wanted try to put my application on my android devices but I'm facing a problem ...

When I run : **ionic cordova run android --device -l -debug**

I have this stack of error and i don't understanding them :

> **Error: Failed to fetch platform cordova-android@^6.3.0**
>
> **Probably this is either a connection problem, or platform spec is incorrect.**
>
> **Check your connection and platform name/version/URL.**
>
> **Error: npm: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output: npm ERR! Linux 4.14.5-1-ARCH npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node"**
>
> **"/home/some/project/node_modules/.bin/npm" "install" "cordova-android@^6.3.0" "--production" "--save-exact" npm ERR! node
>   v9.3.0 npm ERR! npm  v2.15.12 npm ERR! code EPEERINVALID**
>
> **npm ERR! peerinvalid The package @angular/common@4.4.5 does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!**
>
> **npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @angular/forms@4.4.5 wants @angular/common@4.4.5**
>
> **npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @angular/platform-browser@4.4.5 wants @angular/common@4.4.5**
>
> **npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@4.4.5 wants @angular/common@4.4.5**
>
> **npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @ngx-translate/http-loader@2.0.0 wants @angular/common@>=4.3.0**
>
> **npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer ionic-angular@3.7.1 wants @angular/common@4.4.3**
>
> **npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer ng2-charts@1.6.0 wants @angular/common@^2.3.0 || >=4.0.0**

Someone know how to resolve it or have an idea ?

I thank you in advance for any answer or help you could bring me.

Q.R

Answer (score 0):

Try to run this command first.

```
cordova platform add android@6.2.3

cordova build android
```

and you could use android studio to build after create android platform.